# Gearman background job status callbacks

Tags: php, gearman

I'm working with Gearman's background tasks.

If you read in the code sample at http://www.php.net/manual/en/gearmanclient.addtaskstatus.php, you will see following comment:

```
/* Poll the server to see when those background jobs finish; */
/* a better method would be to use event callbacks */
```

What ARE those event callbacks, exactly?

I have tried the following:

```
    $client->setCreatedCallback(function(GearmanTask $task){
    });
    $client->setExceptionCallback(function(GearmanTask $task){
    });
    $client->setFailCallback(function(GearmanTask $task){
    });
```

but none of them fire when tasks are added with $client->doBackground().

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Background tasks are called such because they allow the client that submitted them to un-block and work disconnected. They do not keep a channel of communication open to the client, so you won't get any of those status updates. 
If you want to check the status of background job use GearmanClient::jobStatus.
See [here](http://php.net/manual/en/gearmanclient.dobackground.php) and [here](http://php.net/manual/en/gearmanjob.sendstatus.php).